# Keeping track of scopes while generating LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm-c++-api

I am writing a compiler for a simple imperative language. This language allows encapsulated function definitions (like Python). These functions (their bodies) play the role of scopes, which means that if a variable `x` is declared inside a function `foo`, then it is not visible outside of it, but `x` is visible inside functions that are defined after `x`, inside `foo`. The same applies for functions and, of course, variable and function shadowing is allowed.

Is there a standard/recommended way provided by the LLVM C++ API to keep track of which variables/functions are visible while generating LLVM IR for my language at any given moment (like a "stack of scopes" of sorts)?

Right now, I keep track of these with a custom logger class of mine.